# Hyperlink to section sends me to below menu-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just (thanks to the help of stack overflow users) created a menu-bar with hyperlinks to sections. Everything works perfectly but there is one strange happening. Every time I click on a link in the menu, the browser will position the page such that the menu bar is just above the view (you have to scroll up to see it again) - in other words it positions me mid-page instead of at the top of the page. (I have a lot of content in the sections which is why I would like to fix it so we always start at the top).

Here is the Html, js and CSS code:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a class="active" href="#content1"><div>Tab1</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#content2"><div>Tab2</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#content3"><div>Tab3</div></a></li>
</ul>

<section id="content1">
some content 1
</section>

<section id="content2" >
some content 2
</section>


<section id="content3" >
some content 3
</section>
```

js code:

```
            $('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(){
                $('section').hide();
                $($(this).attr('href')).show();
                var $this = $(this),
                $ul = $this.parents('ul');
                $ul.find('a').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
            });
```

CSS code:

```
section {
    display: none;
}

section:first-of-type {
    display:block;
}

ul.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    color: #349cf0;
}

ul.tabs li a.active {
    color: #349cf0;
}
```

You won't be able to see the problem with this code (unless you put in a hell-uv-alot of 
 or content within the  tags. However I hope you understand the problem - the code sends you to the top of the section-tag instead of the top of the whole html page. I'm thinking this could maybe be fixed in the js code or perhaps anybody know of a smart fix to the  tags in the html?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the hyperlink. You can take a look of [LINK WITHIN A PAGE](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm). So do not provide id as href.

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(){
             $('section').hide();
                $($(this).attr('data-url')).show();
                var $this = $(this),
                $ul = $this.parents('ul');
                $ul.find('a').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
            }); 
        });
```

```css
     #header { 
         border-bottom: black 1px solid;
     }
     section {
         display: none;
         height: 500px;
         border: black 2px solid;
     }

     section:first-of-type {
         display:block;
     }

     ul.tabs {
         list-style: none;
         text-align: center;
     }

     ul.tabs li {
         display: inline-block;
     }

     ul.tabs li a {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100px;
         margin-right: 25px;
         margin-bottom: 25px;
         padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         border: 1px;
         border-style: solid;
         border-color: #000000;
         text-align: center;
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #000000;
     }

     ul.tabs li a:hover {
         color: #349cf0;
     }

     ul.tabs li a.active {
         color: #349cf0;
     }
     .content {
         margin-top: 
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div id="header">
         <h1>Header Part</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
          <ul class="tabs">
             <li>
                <a class="active" 
                   href="javascript:void(0);" 
                   data-url="#content1">
                    <div>Tab1</div>
                 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                   data-url="#content2">
                    <div>Tab2</div>
                 </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                   data-url="#content3">
                    <div>Tab3</div>
                 </a>
              </li>
         </ul>
         <section id="content1" style="background-color:red;">
             some content 1
         </section>
         <section id="content2" style="background-color:green;">
            some content 2
         </section>
         <section id="content3" style="background-color:blue;">
            some content 3
         </section>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquerys element.top or element.position- #px.

> https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Hi. I have read through the link but I couldn't really find a solution. I have tried the js code: window.scrollTo(0, 0); However this does nothing at all.